# How can I ping a device outside my VPN network but connected to a router that is in my VPN network

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

A schema will better explain the situation:

[image]

With the computer (`10.8.0.2`) I would like to be able to ping the cameras. From the computer I can already ping the router since the VPN is configured to support client-to-client traffic (i.e. `ping 10.8.0.3` will work if sent by `10.8.0.2`)

I guess that I have to add some routing configuration on the OpenVPN Server.

Something like:

```
route add 192.100.0.2 10.8.0.1 
route add 192.101.0.2 10.8.0.1
```

In my route table ?

The goal is to be able to ping a camera (i.e. ping 192.100.0.2) from the computer (10.8.0.2). But I do not know which routing configuration should be added in order to make that possible.

VPN ifconfig:

```
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
        inet6 fe80::9568:9ac4:b257:8fce  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 61069  bytes 9935578 (9.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 230542  bytes 295296281 (295.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Router1 network:

```
192.100.0.0/16 (255.255.0.0)
```

Router2 network:

```
192.101.0.0/16 (255.255.0.0)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, but having the same IP address in 2 places on your network is a really bad idea.

Comment: @davidgo I am not familiar with network issues, the lack of clarity in my question probably reflects that lack of expertise. What is not understandable? I can edit my question.

Comment: @davidgo I've editer the schema and my question, I hope that it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

> Something like: `route add 192.100.0.2 10.8.0.1`

This specifies the OpenVPN server as a gateway. That makes sense *on the computer* (with the VPN server being the next hop), but not on the VPN server itself. (You can push this route to clients *from* the OpenVPN server config, though.)

The VPN server itself also needs a similar route, but the "next hop" must be, well, the *next* hop – one of your LTE routers, `10.8.0.4` or similar.

> But two routers have the same network prefix (192.100.x.x), should I give a different network prefix for each router ? For example:

You *definitely should,* but it is not enough to just do this in the routing table. If that's all you do, sure, the packets will be delivered to the router – but the router will not recognize them, as it still knows only the original 192.100.x.x.

So in order to do this, you should start by reconfiguring the router itself; the routes will follow from that.

Side note: 192.100.x.x is a **global** address. It's outside the "reserved for local use" 192.168.x.x range. (Specifically, 192.100.0.x/24 has been issued to the "NetVoyage" company in Utah, USA. Various other /24's belong to companies in Europe and Americas.)

If your networks use 192.100.x.x addresses for LANs, and your organization *hasn't* been issued that specific range by ARIN (or RIPE or APNIC or...), then whoever chose those addresses doesn't know what they're doing.

Comment: What you have said here is correct and important, but I suspect is incomplete.  I've always struggled with the Openvpn "iroute" directive - which I'm fairly sure needs to be added to the config as well for routing between 192.10?.x.x - I don't think ip routes by themselves are enough.